# Google chart with ajax request to PHP

Tags: php, json, ajax

I having bit issue with a Google chart and my array.php json data output is follows

```
var jsondata = {"cols":[{"id":"","label":"Topping","type":"string"},{"id":"","label":"Slices","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"MAX"},{"v":150}]},{"c":[{"v":"MAX1"},{"v":59}]},{"c":[{"v":"MAX2"},{"v":15}]},{"c":[{"v":"MAX3"},{"v":153}]},{"c":[{"v":"MAX4"},{"v":8}]},{"c":[{"v":"MAX5"},{"v":25}]},{"c":[{"v":"MAX6"},{"v":65}]}]}
```

this work fine with google chart

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsond);

var chart = new 
google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

chart.draw(data, options);

When i call trough the ajax i am getting error saying invalid json.

var jsonData = $.ajax({
              url: "array.php",
              dataType:"json",
              async: false
              }).responseText;

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

var chart = new 
google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

chart.draw(data, options);
```

Someone explain on this.

Answer (score 1):

jsonData is a string (responseText)
parse it to json

```
jQuery.parseJSON(jsonData)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your PHP code is outputting, but make sure there is a **json_encode($array);** in your php echo statement.

Other than that, log the json data that's coming from your AJAX request using the Google Chrome dev console to see if it matches the json in your **jsondata** variable and make changes in the output format accordingly.

Sometimes, you may be making a mistake of adding/not-adding the square brackets [ ]. 
Take care of that as well.

Also, if your PHP is generating the array, make sure it's structure matches the one required. (Sometimes we make silly mistakes)

Comment: Already i did this json_encode($array) in my array.php and outputting format is show above which i have assigned a variable to jsondata

Comment: Then you need to run a jQuery.parseJSON(jsonData);